# Creating paper curl using CSS3

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<div class="box">Paper Curl</div>
```

CSS3 code:

```
.box
{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    background: #f0ab67;
}

.box:before, .box:after
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 10px;
    content: ' ';
    left: 12px;
    bottom: 12px;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: -1;
}

.box:after
{
    left: auto;
    right: 12px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
}
```

Below is the "paper curl" I wanted to achieve:

http://postimg.org/image/v0l84bmdv/

Below is the curve I could make so far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BCLpE

Can anyone help me out on how to achieve the curves as perfect as in the image? I am not sure whether to go with image or we can do it with CSS3 itself.

Comment: what you've done is not that bad, it looks fairly OK :)

Comment: @KingKing: Can't we achive exactly out there?

Comment: tunning a bit the blur and rotation should do it, nop ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jiaCq

Comment: Just one obvious point to mention, CSS effects probably won't work in IE8.

Comment: you should use the whole `' '` element as a shadow, and not only its `box-shadow`. check my answer

Comment: The `curl` tag is not for page curls...

Comment: Refer this page - http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects

Comment: rotation is not for IE8, but pseudo element can still be used to create unblured shadows in IE8 and older browser. What matters here to give a hint on the tunning of the blur shadow and eventually transform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your demo shows that you had the right direction. You just need to tweak it a little by trial and error. Here is the edited code:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    background: white;/* #f0ab67;*/
    border:1px solid lightgray;
}

.box:before, .box:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 48%;
    height: 10px;
    content: ' ';
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 40px;      
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    -moz-transform-origin: top right;
    -ms-transform-origin: top right;
    transform-origin: top right;

    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 6px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 30px 6px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
     box-shadow: 0 30px 6px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
     z-index: -1;
}

.box:after {
    left: auto;
    right: 20px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

**NOTE**: I've tried using the `white` color instead of the color you used originally to make it look like the paper in the picture. And it may not be exactly what you want, if so just wait for another better answer :)

### [Demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fpjoa)

**Tip**: You can try yourself changing the `box-shadow`, especially the blur and the color to make it exactly what you need. The blur I used in the demo is `6px`, but looks like `4px` is better.

Comment: I see you have applied box-shadow for both after and before. which one is bottom-shadow? and also can u answer this question when free. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488075/adding-margin-top-to-container-bootstrap

Comment: @theJava do you mean the shadow in the middle? it's exactly made of both the box-shadows of the `:before` and `:after`. They cross each other in the middle.

Comment: I got a requirement saying edit the bottom box-shadow. I see only shadow before and after the container. so was confused.

Comment: @theJava it looks fairly like the paper with shadow, at least the color of the shadow (in the middle) should be consistent with the shadow color at the ends. Increasing the shadow width/thickness in the middle will make it look unnatural. So how exactly they want you to modify it?

Comment: They asked me to add the bottom shadow into a separate mixin... i am confused on where is bottom shadow here

Comment: @theJava ah, looks like they mean **all the shadow**, not just the middle shadow. If so, you can just cut all the style for `:before` and `:after`. Removing that style will make the paper *flat* as normal without any shadow. BTW, I've not used mixin, so not sure what it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52088/discussion-between-thejava-and-king-king)

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with my tunning too :) **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/jiaCq/)** *From my earlier comment*

```
/* prefix auto-generated in demo link */.box
{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
 background:white;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
}

.box:before, .box:after
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  content: ' ';    
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 30px;
  transform: 
    skew(-7deg) 
    rotate(-3deg);

  box-shadow: 
    0 30px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: -1;
}

.box:after
{
  left: auto;
  right: 25px;
  transform: 
    skew(4deg) 
    rotate(3deg);
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
body {
  background:#E7EBEC;
}
```

[image: imageVS CSS render]

Answer (score 1):

when creating shadows, sometimes its best to use the elements background as shadow while setting its opacity to a very low number.

here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/M4g6E/)

html:

```
<div class="paper"></div>
```

css:

```
body {
    background:#ededef;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.paper {
        position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
.paper:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 20px;
    content:' ';
    left: 10px;
    bottom: -8px;
    background:black;
    opacity:0.2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg,-5deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0deg,-5deg);
    transform: skew(0deg,-5deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
.paper:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 20px;
    content:' ';
    right: 10px;
    bottom: -8px;
    background:black;
    opacity:0.2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg,5deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0deg,5deg);
    transform: skew(0deg,5deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```