# Adding margin top to container bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML Div container

```
<div class="container margin-top-custom">
</div>
```

CSS Class

```
$margin-xs: 5px;
$margin-sm: 10px;
$margin-md: 15px;
$margin-lg: 30px;
$margin-xl: 100px;

.margin-top-custom{
  margin-top: $margin-xl;
}
```

The above works perfectly fine. I am not sure whether its a right practise to do. How can i add margin to the `container` class itself. Is it a bad practise to add margin to container class and also have i defined the margin in the right way?

Comment: Tbh all of them work, as far as best practice as long as you don't change the bootstrap.css file you're good to go.